# Há diferença de performance entre INNER JOIN e CROSS APPLY?

Tags: sql-server, join, tsql

Estou iniciando os estudos em SQL SERVER e alguns lugares ensinam a usar o `INNER JOIN` para realizar a junção de duas tabelas. Todavia, há alguns outros lugares que ensinam via `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Douglas,
INNER JOIN compara as linhas de duas tabelas baseada em uma condição especificada na consulta. Esse tipo de join é usado na interseção de linhas que tem o mesmo valor em uma coluna (ou mais de uma coluna). As linhas retornadas são somente aquelas que estão não duas tabelas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CROSS JOIN é também chamado de Produto Cartesiano, onde todas as linhas da tabela à esquerda são retornadas e cada uma dessas linhas é combinada com todas as linhas da tabela à direita. Em termos práticos, se a tabela à esquerda tem 10 linhas e a tabela à direita tem 100 linhas, um cross join irá retornar 1000 linhas.

CROSS APPLY é como um cross join, em termos do resultado que ele produz, mas somente é usado com uma função. Com o APPLY, um dos inputs (à direita) não é fisicamente materializado no banco de dados porque o seu output depende dos parâmetros do input, como uma table-valued function, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
SELECT SP.SalesYTD, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.JobTitle FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS SP CROSS APPLY dbo.ufnGetContactInformation (SP.BusinessEntityID) AS P;
```

Não é possível comparar a performance entre INNER JOIN e CROSS APPLY pois eles tem diferentes propósitos.